# Stop sidebar from overlapping sticky footer

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site for a class project and everything is working fine except when I tried to make the footer sticky the sidebar overlaps the footer when content is added dynamically.
I have the sidebar height set to 90vh because I could not figure out how to get the background color to take up the full height of the sidebar when there was no content  I set the sidebar overflow to auto which was working fine but when I try to make the footer sticky it works find until the content grows to big.  Scrollbars do appear but the sidebar overlaps the footer.

Here is the html & css:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.main-image {
  background-image: url(../images/crypto.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  clip: rect(0, 400px, 200px, 0);
}

.sidebar {
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Crypto & Cocktails </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="./assets/images/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- header -->
  <header id="top">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 center #26a69a teal lighten-1">
        <img src="assets/images/cryptococktailsheader.jpg" class="responsive-img" alt="Crypto & Cocktails" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- sidebar -->
      <div class="col s12 l2 #00695c teal darken-3 sidebar">
        <span class="flow-text center">
                    <h5 class="white-text">Search Coinbase</h5>
                    <form id="coin-search" action="">
                        <input id="coin-input" type="text" class="white" name="coin-input"
                            placeholder="Cryptocurrency Ticker">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary submitButton">Search</button>
                          
                    </form>
                </span>

        <div id="myCoins" class="col-12"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 l10 content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 l3 ">
            <h2 id="coin-name"></h2>
            <span id="coin-display" class="flow-text"></span>
            <h3 id="drinkName"></h3>
            <span id="drinkImg"></span>
            <a class="right hide-on-med-and-up" href="#top">Back to top</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12 l7 main-image hide-on-small-only"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer class="#26a69a teal lighten-1 center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Developers - Contact Us</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
        © 2021 Copyright

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Materialize Framewrk -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom Scripts -->
  <script src="./assets/scripts/main.js"></script>
  <script src="./assets/scripts/cocktail.js"></script>
  <script src="./assets/scripts/coinbase.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your HTML code seems to be incomplete, please provide complete code (a [mre]).

Comment: I added the rest of the html

Answer (score 0):

We just had to add the z-index: 1; to the footer.